# When wiring an anlogue switch to grounded button, which goes to Y and Z?

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit

I'm wiring an analogue switch ([74HCT4066N](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4066.pdf)) to throw a grounded switch. The datasheet says that the recommended Vsw value should be between GND and Vcc. This means that it's important which of Y or Z I should connect to ground. Which (Y or Z) should I connect to ground to ensure that my voltage stays positive? (The other end of my switch has a positive voltage relative to ground)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All '4066 switches are bidirectional and bipolar, provided the voltage specs are not violated. They may be connected either way around.

Comment: +1 Voltage specs not violated means that **both** ends of the switch must always be between GND and Vcc for the HCT4066.

Comment: Aaah, thanks for the clarification -- I understand the requirements now. :)